# HostBuilder vs ServiceProvider in dotnet core c# dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

The dotnetcore dependency injection system seems like a big mess. There's so many options and ways to do things.

I came across the generic hostbuilder when all this while i've been reading about ServiceProviders.

Whats the difference and when does one use hostbuilder over simple service provider?